# PFLogInViewController - Cannot customize fields

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parseui

I want to implement ParseUI login screen by subclassing PFLogInViewController. According to documentation, elements could be customized by changing the fields attribute (e.g. add Facebook login button). However, it does not work at all. Note that other customizations (e.g. color) works well.

I also tried to assign fields within init() instead of viewDidLoad(), did not work as well.

Thanks!!

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class LoginViewController: PFLogInViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {

var appDelegate: AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

        println("login")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        self.delegate = self

        self.fields = (
            PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword |
            PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten |
            PFLogInFields.Facebook |
            PFLogInFields.Twitter
        )

        self.logInView.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#FFFFFF")
        self.logInView.tintColor = UIColor(rgba: "#FF2200")

        self.signUpController.delegate = self

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try customizing the fields before you present `LogInViewController`.

Comment: This works, thanks! 

Since in my case, the LoginVC is the initial VC, I just added a preceding VC and customize the LoginVC by overriding prepareForSegue.